# How to set/get the properties Grial Repeater?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

refer to http://docs.grialkit.com/repeater.html, it got a property 
call 'SelectedItem', i want to know the code in detail how to set or get it ?

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will get the `SelectedItem`, I am assuming you are following the MVVM approach.

**XAML:-**

```
<grial:Repeater  Spacing="8" 
                 Padding="10" 
                 ScrollPadding="10" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                 SelectedItem= "{Binding SelectedItemObject}">  
    <grial:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
        <!--DEFAULT ITEM TEMPLATE-->
    </grial:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
</grial:Repeater>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private ModelClass _selectedItemObject;
public ModelClass SelectedItemObject
{
    get { return _selectedItemObject; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItemObject = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItemObject");
        OnItemSelected(SelectedItemObject);
    }
}

private List<ModelClass> _items;
public List<ModelClass> Items
{
   get{ return _items;}
   set
     {
         _items = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Items");
     }
 }

private void OnItemSelected(ModelClass selectedItem)
{
  if (selectedItem == null)
       return;

  // Perform your logic her on selection
}
```

Comment: it this change 'ModelClass' to 'ArticleData' like private ArticleData _selectedItemObject; ? and the code only run one time ? the OnItemSelected never execution ?

Comment: Yes ModelClass is your defined class, ModelClass is just a dummy name

Comment: OnItemSelected executes once while loading the Repeater and will execute when you will select the item from Repeater control